# Querying in postgres for a range around an integer

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql, I'd like to determine whether a known integer is within a +/- range of another integer. What is the function for this query?

Example: In my dataset, I have 2 Tables:

```
Table_1
ID   integer
 1     2000
 2     3000
 3     4000
```

```
Table_2
ID   integer
 1     1995
 2     3050
 3     4100
```

For each ID-pair, I'd like to query whether Table_1.integer is +/- 25 of Table_2.integer.

```
The answers would be:
ID 1: TRUE
ID 2: FALSE
ID 3: FALSE
```

Any help is much appreciated. I am new to using postgresql and all programming languages in general.

Answer (score 1):

We can try checking the absolute value of the difference between the two `integer` values, for each `ID`:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    CASE WHEN ABS(t1.integer - t2.integer) <= 25 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS answer
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

If you want to just output the raw boolean value, then use:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    ABS(t1.integer - t2.integer) <= 25 AS answer
FROM ...
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN ABS(t1.integer - t2.integer) <= 25 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'` can be simplified to `ABS(t1.integer - t2.integer) <= 25`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assume the OP wants actual text string output.  Other than that, I agree with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost similar to @Tim's solution but without the `CASE` expression, useful if you wish to output `boolean` types.

```
SELECT t1.ID,ABS(t1.integer - t2.integer) <= 25 as res
FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c43a65c68e2cdfe82d3b0721a974371a)